# warning in session_start() in php 7.1

Tags: php, session, php-7

my script has a problem and gives me this warning:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path:
>   /Users/soroush/Documents/www/new/tmp/session) in
>   /Users/soroush/Documents/www/new/include/class.session.php on line 35

this is my class:

```
class SecureSessionHandler extends SessionHandler {
    protected $key, $name, $cookie;
    public function __construct($name = 'MY_SESSION', $cookie = [])
    {
        $this->key = SESSION_KEY;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->cookie = $cookie;
        $this->cookie += [
        'lifetime' => 0,
        'path'     => ini_get('session.cookie_path'),
        'domain'   => ini_get('session.cookie_domain'),
        'secure'   => isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']),
        'httponly' => true
        ];
        $this->setup();
    }
    private function setup()
    {
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
        session_name($this->name);
        session_set_cookie_params(
        $this->cookie['lifetime'],
        $this->cookie['path'],
        $this->cookie['domain'],
        $this->cookie['secure'],
        $this->cookie['httponly']
        );
    }
    public function start()
    {
        if (session_id() === '') {
        if (session_start()) {
        return mt_rand(0, 4) === 0 ? $this->refresh() : true; // 1/5
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
    public function forget()
    {
    if (session_id() === '') {
    return false;
    }
    $_SESSION = [];
    setcookie(
    $this->name,
    '',
    time() - 42000,
    $this->cookie['path'],
    $this->cookie['domain'],
    $this->cookie['secure'],
    $this->cookie['httponly']
    );
    return session_destroy();
    }
    public function refresh()
    {
    return session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
    public function read($id)
    {
        $data = openssl_decrypt(parent::read($id),'AES256',$this->key);
        return $data;

    }
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
    return parent::write($id, openssl_encrypt(parent::read($id),'AES256',$this->key));
    }
    public function isExpired($ttl = 30)
    {
    $last = isset($_SESSION['_last_activity'])
    ? $_SESSION['_last_activity']
    : false;
    if ($last !== false && time() - $last > $ttl * 60) {
    return true;
    }
    $_SESSION['_last_activity'] = time();
    return false;
    }
    public function isFingerprint()
    {
    $hash = md5(
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] .
    (ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long('255.255.0.0'))
    );
    if (isset($_SESSION['_fingerprint'])) {
    return $_SESSION['_fingerprint'] === $hash;
    }
    $_SESSION['_fingerprint'] = $hash;
    return true;
    }
    public function isValid()
    {
    return ! $this->isExpired() && $this->isFingerprint();
    }
    public function get($name)
    {
    $parsed = explode('.', $name);
    $result = $_SESSION;
    while ($parsed) {
    $next = array_shift($parsed);
    if (isset($result[$next])) {
    $result = $result[$next];
    } else {
    return null;
    }
    }
    return $result;
    }
    public function put($name, $value)
    {
    $parsed = explode('.', $name);
    $session =& $_SESSION;
    while (count($parsed) > 1) {
    $next = array_shift($parsed);
    if ( ! isset($session[$next]) || ! is_array($session[$next])) {
    $session[$next] = [];
    }
    $session =& $session[$next];
    }
    $session[array_shift($parsed)] = $value;
    }
}
```

and i use this class like this:

```
$session = new SecureSessionHandler();
    ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
    session_set_save_handler($session, true);
    session_save_path(SITE_PATH.'tmp/session');
    $session->start();
    if ( ! $session->isValid(5)) {
        $session->destroy();
        die();
    }
    $session->put('site.langu', $lang->lang);
```

but it give me a warning in php 7.1
i use a mac os system and do this works

1. give 0777 permission to session folder
2. change chown with php running group and user

what should I do to fix this warning?

i solved this problem with this change:

```
  public function read($id)
    {
        return (string)openssl_decrypt (parent::read($id) , "aes-256-cbc", $this->key);
    }
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        return parent::write($id, openssl_encrypt($data, "aes-256-cbc", $this->key));
    }
```

viva google :))

Comment: if (session_id() === '') looks really weird to me...

Comment: hi
thanks for your reply.
i change my code to this:
        if (session_start()) {
        return mt_rand(0, 4) === 0 ? $this->refresh() : true; // 1/5
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
but noting change :(

Comment: Does `SITE_PATH.'tmp/session' ` resolves to `/Users/soroush/Documents/www/new/tmp/session` ?

Comment: hi, thanks for response, yes, it does, my php version is 7.1.8 on mamp pro.